# Regular Expression to split string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse the below string :

> *A. BOSCOLO1,4, J. A. STARR2, N. LUNARDI4, C. ORI4, J. P. BENNETT, Jr3,  V. JEVTOVIC-TODOROVIC2,3,4,

The output expected is below :

> *A. BOSCOLO1,4
>   J. A. STARR2
>   N. LUNARDI4 
>  C. ORI4 
>   J. P. BENNETT, Jr3
>    V. JEVTOVIC-TODOROVIC2,3,4

I can not split them on the delimiter (,) as it's inconsistent  . The above are the names followed by one or more digits. Words followed by digit & commas until next word and No names are allowed which do not have any digits. 
I have no idea how to write REGEX for the same . Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Comma can't be used as a split char because the comma it's actually part of the word. Also there is nothing to tell where the Regular expression should start doing it's split job. You could try using the numbers instead.

Comment: Yeah its like words followed by digit & commas until next word .

Comment: What about `, Jr3` ... that's the actually difficult part ... @Burfi are there other such strings that don't conform to "only digits after names", or is Jr3 or Jr[digit] the only possibility?

Comment: No words are allowed which do not have any digits .

Comment: Forget what I said... `, Jr` is obviously part of the name, and 3 is only one digit. so what other strings do you have instead of `, Jr`?

Comment: Burfi's got it.  Split it on a comma after a digit.

Comment: actually, split on `, ` after digit

Comment: @m.buettner : yeah , split , after digit followed by word ? otherwise fails for name 1,2,3

Comment: @Burfi what I mean is that you replace digit-comma-space, by digit-linebreak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression like this:;

```
[*A-Z]\D+\d+(,\d+)*
```

Example:

```
string data = "*A. BOSCOLO1,4, J. A. STARR2, N. LUNARDI4, C. ORI4, J. P. BENNETT, Jr3, V. JEVTOVIC-TODOROVIC2,3,4,";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(data, @"[*A-Z]\D+\d+(,\d+)*");

foreach (Match x in matches) {
  Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Output:

```
*A. BOSCOLO1,4
J. A. STARR2
N. LUNARDI4
C. ORI4
J. P. BENNETT, Jr3
V. JEVTOVIC-TODOROVIC2,3,4
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa , I have tested the above regex with different inputs and its working fine . Thanks a lot.